# Cannot access my public IP outside the network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

So I want to test opening one port to the public. I know how to do port forwarding in the router and I have done so. I tested this with gameranger and it works. I check my global IP, say it is 121.111.`*`.`*`, with websites like `myglobalip.com` (there are many alternatives). I can also confirm this is the IP in the ssh login message as well. 
Now I tried to do `telnet 121.111.*.* 8888`  in my wifi network, it says connection refused, but at least it means I can access it. It will work for `telnet 121.111.*.* 443`, therefore I suspect this is the IP address of the router. 
The problem I do not understand is that if I try the same command inside the SSH instance it will not work (`telnet 121.111.*.* 8888` ). Everything results in time out. I tried to monitor the log in wireshark and nothing says the port 8888 I have entered. I am sure that the outward traffic is not restricted in the instance because I can telnet to 8.8.8.8. Surely there must be a way the internet communicate with the router, otherwise it should not be able to connect to the internet. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Check your router web interface. If you don't see this public IP somewhere in it (e.g. in log when establishing internet connection) then the public IP is not your router public IP but a CGNAT system of your provider.

Comment: I did check it. The problem is that it is a Japanese router. And it looks like it is not shown in the router actually. So what happens in this case?

Comment: That means your router does not have a public IP -> you can run a service that is accessible from the internet. You can try to set-up a service on IPV6 if your provider assigns you a IPv6 address range or try a VPN that provides a public IP.

Comment: To test the connection, & to ensure it doesn't rely on hairpinning, you need to access from your phone when it *is not on the same network*. Disable wifi & use the  phone's data connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions. The truth of this problem is, my router did not have an IP address as Robert has pointed out. Because it is behind another router. Japanese ISP usually provide you a "home gateway" which is router without WIFI. By default, it does not come with WIFI so I had to buy another router just for the WIFI functionality (it is possible to include the WIFI functionality but it will require additional payment **per month** so it is cheaper to just buy a router). However this creates a rather confusing scenario of "router behind router". In conclusion setting the second router does not really work because it is the first router that handles the address translation. 
The solution is, disable the second router as router and just use it as a WIFI (in Japanese they call this bridge mode and it is easily configurable by flipping the switch). The do all the normal port configuration on the "home gateway", now I can `telnet` with my designated port.